# i can´t convert ToolStripComboBox SelectedValue to Int32 C#

Tags: c#

I have a C# ToolStripComboBox binded to a data table, when I change the Selection (event) I try to get the SelectedValue, and the error message says that property is DataRowView, and when I cast it as DataRowView, the error message says that I can´t convert from Int32 to DataRowView. How can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working fine for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("desc", typeof(System.String));

            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["id"] = i;
                dr["desc"] = i.ToString() + " desc";

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;

            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted += ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted;

            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "id";
            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "desc";
            toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dt;


        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            int v = Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedItem)["id"].ToString());

            MessageBox.Show("User Selected " + v.ToString());
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //this line will give you the 


        }

        private void toolStripComboBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to get the SelectedValue as Int32

Comment: you have to do this with the selectedvalue:

Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)toolstrip.SelectedValue)["ID"].ToString()) like this

Comment: this: Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)comboBox.SelectedValue)["Id"].ToString()) throws error "Unable to cast from type System.Int32 to type System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: don't use the same name "Id"  use the name on the basis of which you want to identify the record. can you give me the sample of value that you are trying to cast to int

Comment: and in this case if I point with the mouse the SelectedValue in the source code I can see the number

Comment: please paste some code and sample data so i can understand what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: sorry I don´t understand "the name on the basis of which you want to identify the record"

Comment: in the Load event handler        toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Table"];
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Desc";
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";

Comment: i mean to say you are binding the datatable to ToolStripComboBox and datatable contains following column  recordid,recorddescription,recordate etc.. and recordid is the one the that is use to identify the data than you have to use DataRowViewObject["recordid"]

Comment: in the SelectionChangeComitted event handler:    (here I want to get the toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.SelectedValue)

Comment: give me the event name in which you are trying to get the name

Comment: i have posted the whole code that i have just created

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged is the event where I try to get SelectedValue as Int32

Comment: check the code run it in some windows form application hope that works for you i have altered it as per SelectionChangeCommitted

Comment: I found another way to do what I needed, thank you anyway